# Games lock up when running SLI

Tags: windows-7, sli

My specs:
Windows 7 64bit Ultimate RC
Intel C2D E8500
4gb RAM
Asus Striker II
2x Nvidia GeFoce 260 GTX
OCZ GameXStream 700W 'Dual GPU Ready' PSU

I have Windows 7 RTM but I haven't gotten around to reinstalling it yet.

My issue is, whenever I turn on SLI mode, games will lock up after a few minutes of playing. Temps are fine, nothing is over-clocked and I've got water cooling going to the CPU and GPUs. I've been trying unsuccessfully to troubleshoot the issue myself but I have run into a wall and can't figure out what else to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, in my experience, problems like that are always caused by 3 things:

1. Heat
2. Power
3. Drivers

You already said that 1 wasn't a problem. I wouldn't be surprised of NVidia's Win7 drivers weren't 100% just yet (either cause of the drivers or Win 7 itself), but I would also look at your PSU. I don't know the power requirements of a 260GTX but you might want to check to be sure your PSU can support 2 of those cards.

Comment: I believe my PSU is 650w or 750w. It was branded 'SLI Ready' so I assume that it should be enough power for it, but you know what they say about assuming... My drivers are the latests and I even ran a driver cleaner before updating. I've not read anything about anyone else having these issues with windows7 and sli so I'm pretty sure its not a driver issue. I may just breakdown and load my RTM copy of Windows 7 to see if that helps any.

Comment: The nVidia drivers are probably fine. I am running Windows 7 RC x64 with a 295 (SLI on a card), and it works fine with in SLI mode. I would look at RAM and the mobo drivers (what RAM is in the system btw?)

Comment: I believe it is G.SKILL. The RAM is brand new and I believe I was having this issue before I replaced the RAM. I had also replaced the MOBO when I replaced the RAM too. I believe I was using an EVGA 750i FTW or something like that. I will try updating the chipset drivers when I get home tonight and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: SLI ready doesn't mean much. What are the specs on the PSU? Maybe a link to the manufacturer's page would help. I'd guess there aren't enough amps available under max load if heat and drivers aren't an issue.

Comment: +1 MarkM.  If you cheaped out on the power supply, I'd be pointing my finger directly at it as the cause.  Buy a brand name power supply!

Comment: I have a Thermaltake PSU. I'm not sure the exact model though.

Comment: Ok... I found out what exactly the PSU was: OCZ GamerXStream 700W. It specifically states that it is Dual GPU ready.

Comment: Dual GPU ready doesn't mean anything. It's dual GPU ready if it can run two 7600GS cards. You really need to look at the power draw in amps spec'd for your cards and 12V amps available from your PSU.

Comment: The PSU has 4 12v at 18amps. All nVidia says about the card is that it needs 2x 6pin connectors.

Comment: The card is spec'd to draw 182W, which means about 15A from the 12v. You should be OK there unless your PSU is dying and not living up to spec

Comment: Well, I played around with it some more, tweaked some settings in the SLI performance area and haven't had a crash yet... maybe it was just a few games 0.o? anyway... I'll go ahead and mark this as answered.